# How to check which index in a loop is executing without slow down process?

Tags: performance, loops, for-loop

What is the best way to check which index is executing in a loop without too much slow down the process?

For example I want to find all long fancy numbers and have a loop like

```
for( long i = 1; i > 0; i++){
    //block
}
```

and I want to learn which i is executing in real time.

Several ways I know to do in the block are printing i every time, or checking if(i % 10000), or adding a listener.

Which one of these ways is the fastest. Or what do you do in similar cases? Is there any way to access the value of the i manually?

Comment: "I want to learn which `i` is executing in real time". When do you want to learn it, and how often? Are you displaying it somewhere?

Comment: Accuracy is not so important, I want to see the count in order to make sure it works without problem and have an estimate about when it will end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of my recent experience is with Java, so I'd write something like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong(1); // initialize to 1
        LoopMonitor lm = new LoopMonitor(atomicLong);
        Thread t = new Thread(lm);
        t.start(); // start LoopMonitor

        while(atomicLong.get() > 0) {
            long l = atomicLong.getAndIncrement(); // equivalent to long l = atomicLong++ if atomicLong were a primitive
            //block
        }
    }

    private static class LoopMonitor implements Runnable {
        private final AtomicLong atomicLong;

        public LoopMonitor(AtomicLong atomicLong) {
            this.atomicLong = atomicLong;
        }

        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                System.out.println(atomicLong.longValue()); // Print l
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for one second
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most AtomicLong implementations can be set in one clock cycle even on 32-bit platforms, which is why I used it here instead of a primitive long (you don't want to inadvertently print a half-set long); look into your compiler / platform details to see if you need something like this, but if you're on a 64-bit platform then you can probably use a primitive long regardless of which language you're using.  The modified for loop doesn't take much of an efficiency hit - you've replaced a primitive long with a reference to a long, so all you've added is a pointer dereference.

Comment: First of all thanks.

When I tried to compile your code I got this error:

ThreadListener.java:25: error: <identifier> expected >>
 t.start();

I imported Thread lib, what is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure - edit your code into your original question and I'll take a look

Comment: It is completely your code without change. I just pasted it into a class. [link](http://codepaste.net/hkcbd8)

I tried to compile it with Java 7 and Sublime Text 2 on Windows 8 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be easy, but probably the only way to probe the value without affecting the process is to access the loop variable in shared memory with another thread. Threading libraries vary from one system to another, so I can't help much there (on Linux I'd probably use pthreads). The "monitor" thread might do something like probe the value once a minute, sleep()ing in between, and so allowing the first thread to run uninterrupted.

Answer (score 1):

To have a null cost reporting (on multi-cpu computers) : set your index as a "global" property (class-wide for instance), and have a separate thread to read and report the index value.
This report could be timer-based (5 times per seconds or so).

Rq : Maybe you'll need also a boolean stating 'are we in the loop ?'.

Answer (score 1):

**Volatile and Caches**

If you're going to be doing this in, say, C / C++ and use a separate monitor thread as previously suggested then you'll have to make the global/static loop variable volatile. You don't want the compiler decide deciding to use a register for the loop variable. Some toolchains make that assumption anyway, but there's no harm being explicit about it.

And then there's the small issue of caches. A separate monitor thread nowadays will end up on a separate core, and that'll mean that the two separate cache subsystems will have to agree on what the value is. That will unavoidably have a small impact on the runtime of the loop.

**Real real time constraint?**

So that begs the question of just how real time is your loop anyway? I doubt that your timing constraint is such that you're depending on it running within a specific number of CPU clock cycles. Two reasons, a) no modern OS will ever come close to guaranteeing that, you'd have to be running on the bare metal, b) most CPUs these days vary their own clock rate behind your back, so you can't count on a specific number of clock cycles corresponding to a specific real time interval.

**Feature rich solution**

So assuming that your real time requirement is not that constrained, you may wish to do a more capable monitor thread. Have a shared structure protected by a semaphore which your loop occasionally updates, and your monitor thread periodically inspects and reports progress. For best performance the monitor thread would take the semaphore, copy the structure, release the semaphore and then inspect/print the structure, minimising the semaphore locked time.

The only advantage of this approach over that suggested in previous answers is that you could report more than just the loop variable's value. There may be more information from your loop block that you'd like to report too.

Mutex semaphores in, say, C on Linux are pretty fast these days. Unless your loop block is very lightweight the runtime overhead of a single mutex is not likely to be significant, especially if you're updating the shared structure every 1000 loop iterations. A decent OS will put your threads on separate cores, but for the sake of good form you'd make the monitor thread's priority higher than the thread running the loop. This would ensure that the monitoring does actually happen if the two threads do end up on the same core.